# Why CharMap in Ubuntu for lydian not showing up the correct character set

Tags: fonts

Why `CharMap` in Ubuntu 11.04 for lydian not showing up the correct character set. I checked couple of different character sets(Javanese), its showing up the same boxed hexdecimal values.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your font has no support for this codepoint. The site [FileFormat.info](http://fileformat.info/) is a good resource to find information about Unicode characters and fonts. If you look up the [Lydian letter G (U+10922)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10922/index.htm), you'll find some general information. Furthermore there is a link [»fonts that support U+10922«](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10922/fontsupport.htm). Here you find 4 fonts which support this lydian letter. I chose as an example [Quivira](http://www.quivira-font.com/). You can download the [TrueType font file (`.ttf`)](http://www.quivira-font.com/files/Quivira.ttf). After the download finished doubleclick on the file and a font viewer will open. In the bottom right side is a button to install the font. When this is finished, you will have support for the lydian letter G in your system.

The letter looks like: 
[image]